# Creating a scaling timeline in tkinter without matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a timeline in tkinter to plot datetime objects. The dates may be years apart, but there won't be a great deal of them (20 max). I'd like the line to scale, so the first date is at the start of the line and the last is at the end of the line with markers for the dates in between.

I don't need it to do anything fancy, but I do need to show the distance between gaps of time rather than just an ordered grid of labels.

Whilst matplotlib has a great solution for this, I can't use it as it explodes the file size (I'm packaging this up) and I have no other use for it in the project. I've also looked at the [ttkwidgets timeline](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkwidgets/blob/master/ttkwidgets/timeline.py) but that's geared towards times rather than dates and hasn't seemed to work with the times I've given it.

As such, I'm thinking that I'll need to use a Canvas widget, and draw a line which scales dynamically. I'd then need to plot markers which take into account that scaling Any hints would be useful.

Comment: Well I have not voted yet but my guess at a glance is likely due to not providing your code attempt. "No code attempt" is often a reason for down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is what I got so far. Its not perfect but it should be able it illustrate how one could build a dynamic timeline based on submitted dates.

This example will create labels on a canvas spaced out based on how many days are between them.

You will be able to click on the labels to get the notes that were saved with the day you clicked on.

I have provided a scrollbar for when you have many dates and cannot see them all on the screen.

You will also notice that you cannot submit the same day twice. Though you may wish to add a function that allows you to update the notes for that date.

You will need to `pip` install `tkcalendar` for this unless you wish to build your own date selector. But that is a lot of work for no good reason.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar


class Timeline(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.timeline_list = []
        self.timeline_canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.note_textbox = tk.Text(self, height=3)
        self.text_label = tk.Label(self, text='Notes on date: ')
        self.date_button = tk.Button(self, text='Submit new date', command=self.date_selector)
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file='1x1.png')

        self.date_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.text_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.note_textbox.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
        self.timeline_canvas.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')

        bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal')
        bar.config(command=self.timeline_canvas.xview)
        bar.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='ew')

    def on_click(self, event, data="No data!"):
        """You could build a popup menu here that
         is activated on mouse-over or on-click
         I just used print to test the field"""
        print(data)

    def append_canvas(self):
        list_len = len(self.timeline_list)
        if list_len > 1:
            first_date = self.timeline_list[0][0]
            last_date = self.timeline_list[-1][0]
            line_length = last_date - first_date
            self.timeline_list.sort()
            right_side = 50
            self.timeline_canvas.delete('all')
            list_of_dates = []
            for i in range(list_len):
                if i == 0:
                    list_of_dates.append([self.timeline_list[i], 0])
                elif i == list_len-1:
                    list_of_dates.append([self.timeline_list[i], line_length.days])
                else:
                    list_of_dates.append(
                        [self.timeline_list[i], (self.timeline_list[i][0] - self.timeline_list[0][0]).days])

            for ndex, date_item in enumerate(list_of_dates):
                lbl = tk.Label(self.timeline_canvas, text=date_item[0][0], background='gray')
                self.timeline_canvas.create_window((right_side, 25), window=lbl)
                if ndex < len(list_of_dates)-1:
                    right_side += (65 + list_of_dates[ndex+1][1])

                lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, d=date_item[0][1].strip(): self.on_click(event, d))

    def date_selector(self):
        def work_selection():
            selected_date = cal.selection_get()
            selected_notes = self.note_textbox.get(1.0, 'end')
            match_found = False
            for each_list in self.timeline_list:
                if selected_date == each_list[0]:
                    match_found = True
                    break
            if match_found is False:
                self.timeline_list.append([selected_date, selected_notes])
                self.append_canvas()
            top.destroy()
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        cal = Calendar(top, selectmode='day')
        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(top, text="ok", width=10, command=work_selection).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Timeline().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.
I will work on this some more later if I have time.

UPDATE:

I have modified the code to consist on a line that is 500 pixels long.
I have done a bit of testing to make sure everything sits properly on the line.

I may modify it later if I find issues with it but for now I think this should work for all your listed needs.

I did notice one possible issue. Of a set of dates are really close to each other they will overlap each other if there is a large gap between the 1st and last date. I will try to find a better solutions but this is as far as I got today.

Update:

I have also added a zoom options that works with the mouse wheel. Right now you will have to use the scrollbar to move around the canvas when you zoom in but it should work for dates that are close and overlapping visually.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar


class Timeline(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.timeline_list = []
        self.line_size = 500
        self.timeline_canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.note_textbox = tk.Text(self, height=3)
        self.text_label = tk.Label(self, text='Notes on date: ')
        self.date_button = tk.Button(self, text='Submit new date', command=self.date_selector)
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file='1x1.png')

        self.date_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.text_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.note_textbox.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
        self.timeline_canvas.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')

        bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal')
        bar.config(command=self.timeline_canvas.xview)
        bar.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.timeline_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.zoom_in_out)

    def zoom_in_out(self, event):
        if event.delta < 0:
            self.line_size -= 100
        else:
            self.line_size += 100
        self.append_canvas()

    def on_click(self, event=None, date=None, data=None):
        """You could build a popup menu here that
         is activated on mouse-over or on-click
         I just used print to test the field"""
        print(date, data)

    def append_canvas(self):
        list_len = len(self.timeline_list)
        if list_len > 1:
            self.timeline_list.sort()
            first_date = self.timeline_list[0][0]
            last_date = self.timeline_list[-1][0]
            line_length = last_date - first_date
            self.timeline_canvas.delete('all')
            list_of_dates = []
            for i in range(list_len):
                if i == 0:
                    list_of_dates.append([self.timeline_list[i], 0])
                elif i == list_len-1:
                    list_of_dates.append([self.timeline_list[i], line_length.days])
                else:
                    list_of_dates.append(
                        [self.timeline_list[i], (self.timeline_list[i][0] - self.timeline_list[0][0]).days])
            self.timeline_canvas.create_line(50, 50, 550, 50, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))
            for ndex, date_item in enumerate(list_of_dates):
                if ndex == 0:
                    lbl = tk.Label(self.timeline_canvas, text=ndex + 1, background='gray')
                    self.timeline_canvas.create_window((50, 50), window=lbl)
                elif ndex == len(list_of_dates) - 1:
                    lbl = tk.Label(self.timeline_canvas, text=ndex + 1, background='gray')
                    self.timeline_canvas.create_window((self.line_size + 50, 50), window=lbl)
                else:
                    x = (list_of_dates[ndex][1] / list_of_dates[-1][1]) * self.line_size
                    lbl = tk.Label(self.timeline_canvas, text=ndex + 1, background='gray')
                    self.timeline_canvas.create_window((x + 50, 50), window=lbl)
                lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, d=date_item[0][0], t=date_item[0][1].strip(): self.on_click(event, d, t))

    def date_selector(self):
        def work_selection():
            selected_date = cal.selection_get()
            selected_notes = self.note_textbox.get(1.0, 'end')
            match_found = False
            for each_list in self.timeline_list:
                if selected_date == each_list[0]:
                    match_found = True
                    break
            if match_found is False:
                self.timeline_list.append([selected_date, selected_notes])
                self.append_canvas()
            top.destroy()
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        cal = Calendar(top, selectmode='day')
        cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(top, text="ok", width=10, command=work_selection).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Timeline().mainloop()
```

New results:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your time, that's a fantastic start  - just the sort of thing I was looking for. However, If you do happen to get any extra time I'd appreciate anything further you can do. The main issue is that with dates far apart (say 10 years) it causes a lot of scrolling - if you knew of a way to make the dates fit on a fixed sized canvas that would be great. No need for the dates (as they get a bit long) - representative numbers would work instead if that's easier and I can put a table to show which number refers to which date.

Comment: @Retro I think I could manage that. Instead of applying dates you can apply the index value of the list + 1. This would give you a number representation. Instead of spacing out each item basted on days apart you could do some math to limit the overall size to say 400 pixels wide so you can have a finite line that can scale with however many dates you need. I can probably work on this a little today. Let me see what I can do later when I get home.

Comment: Hi Mike, did you get a chance to give it a look? no problem if you won't get chance.

Comment: @Retro I did update my post with my latest code. Check out the latest update at the bottom of my post and let me know if you have any questions. I believe it is much closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic - spot on and I've learnt a lot. Couldn't be happier!

Comment: @Retro glad to help. It was fun working out the math needed to get this to work right.